# Detect Single Modifier Key Change in UIKit for Mac (Catalyst)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uikitformac, mac-catalyst

I am porting an iOS app on MacOS using *UIKit for Mac* also known as *iPad Apps for Mac* or *Project Catalyst*.

The app uses [`keyCommands` from `UIKit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621141-keycommands) to detect a single modifier key press:

```
UIKeyCommand(input: "", modifierFlags: .shift, action: #selector(singleShift))
```

This code works perfectly on iPad with an external keyboard, I am getting the event fired with every single ⇧ press. However, this does not work on MacOS, although single non-modifier events and modifier + non-modifier combinations work.

How do I achieve the desired behavior and get notified about single modifier key events?

Or maybe I should just give up on `UIKeyCommand` and try `UIGestureRecognizer` instead?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your problem make sure you don't have any keyboard apps or apps that intercept keyboard input running. I had a problem like this when I had Karibeaner-elements installed.

Otherwise, if this is a limitation of catalyst consider wrapping a [more stable API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/modifierflags) from app kit or use `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer doesn't (as far as I know) provide a way to detect modifier keys. Am I missing something? My workaround now is as you suggest just to load an AppKit bundle. It would be nice to be able to do this in UIKit though.

Comment: I think you're correct, My suggestion was based on the OP saying they could use UIGestureRecognizer as a workaround, I wasn't aware of it's capability of recognizing mod keys

Comment: @ConfusedVorlon UIGestureRecognizer does provide a `.modifierFlags` property.

Comment: @MinshengLiu - nice spot. Added in 13.4 - perhaps Apple do listen ;)

Comment: @ConfusedVorlon Didn't realize that it was so new. I am really lucky then!